# R and fix protocol

Tags: r, fix-protocol

Is there any way  to connect FIX protocol and R?

FIX protocol gives C# ,JAVA API's to connect. I tried with C# and FIX .

Comment: There is a [dedicated CRAN Task View for finance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html), as well as a [dedicated mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance). And also try `install.packages("sos", dep = TRUE); library(sos); findFn("financial information exchange")`.

Comment: @user3710546 Thanks but that doesn't help. None of the result is valid.

Comment: Could you find a solution ? i am facing the same situation today.